# How to avoid audio delay in Windows media player?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am using `windows media player` in my vb.net application. I am facing a problem that in the videos of channel `cnbc_awaaz`, I am getting audio delay. My application is working fine if I am using videos of channel `IBM lokamat`.

Can anyone suggest me any perfectly compatible `plugin` or `codec` software?

I have installed `K-Lite_Codec_Pack_1015_Full` codec and `hik vision filters`, and using `windows media player`.

Comment: Why is this tagged `mysql`?

Comment: because my database is in mysql.